# header and chapter*

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, starred-version

I find it strange that the page header in the chapter “Title2” is not updated in the example below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Title1}
\lipsum[10]
\clearpage
\chapter*{Title2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title2}
\lipsum{5}
\end{document}
```

What should be done?

Comment: Which header should be updated to what?

Comment: header of chapter*2 was the header of chapter 1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`\chapter*` neither adds a ToC entry nor adjusts the content of headers/footers. For the latter, add `\markboth` with appropriate parameters. EDIT: This results in correct headers/footers for the (default) `twoside` class option; for `oneside`, `\markright` should be used.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Title1}
\lipsum[10]
\clearpage
\chapter*{Title2}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title2}
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Title2}}{}% for "twoside" class option
% \markright{\MakeUppercase{Title2}}% for "oneside" class option
\lipsum{5}
\end{document}
```