# nameref changes header when referencing a chapter*

Tags: table-of-contents, cross-referencing, header-footer, chapters

I'm writing a LaTeX document with `book` as document class and compiled with `pdflatex`. TexLive version is latest 2012.

For introduction (and conclusions) chapter, I'm using:

```
\chapter*{Introduction \markboth{INTRODUCTION}{}}
\label{intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hspace{12pt} Introduction}
```

- `chapter*` because I want it to be non-numbered
- `\markboth` because otherwise header is not "INTRODUCTION" but "CONTENTS" instead (cf. [header and chapter*](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/15918/header-and-chapter) for example)
- `\addcontentsline` to have it appear in the table of contents

But if I reference it using `\nameref{intro}` in another chapter (`\chapter{my chapter}`) then the header of that chapter becomes "INTRODUCTION" instead of "CHAPTER 1 - MY CHAPTER".

Note that if I don't use `\markboth` for the Introduction the header of chapter 1 is correct but the header for the Introduction is not (it becomes "CONTENTS").

Of course if just after the `\nameref{}` in chapter 1, I call `\markboth{CHAPTER 1 - MY CHAPTER}{}` then the chapter 1 header is correct again but this is obviously not practical.

Here is a minimal code showing the problem :

```
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside]{book}

%\usepackage[english]{babel}
% nameref is buggy, when used, header names for chapter in which it is used are wrong
% if previous chapter is a chapter
% even version from 2012/07/31 is buggy ...
\usepackage{nameref}[2012/07/31]

\title{test}
\author{alex}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\maketitle
blabla
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
%\markboth is needed otherwise header is "CONTENTS" instead of "INTRODUCTION" because this is a chapter*{}, not a chapter{}
\chapter*{Introduction \markboth{INTRODUCTION}{}}
\label{intro}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hspace{12pt} Introduction}
blabla.
\newpage
blabla.
\chapter{On the use of Foo in Bar}
\label{chap1}
blabla.
\newpage
And here if I namereference the \nameref{intro} it will break the nice header.
%And here if I namereference the \nameref{intro} with a \markboth{CHAPTER 1 - On the use of Foo in Bar}{} it will do what I need but it is *not* practical at all.

\chapter{On the use of Bar in Foo}
\label{chap2}
blabla.
\chapter*{Conclusions \markboth{CONCLUSIONS}{}}
\label{conclusions}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\hspace{12pt} Conclusions}
blabla.
\newpage
blabla
\chapter{And here too}
\label{chap3}
blabla.
\newpage
blabla with a nameref. to the \nameref{chap1}. cause the same problem, header that should read "CHAPTER 3 - AND HERE TOO" is replaced by "INTRODUCTION".

\backmatter
blabla
\end{document}
```

Comment: putting \markboth *outside* of the chapter{} fixes the issue. I'll answer my own question as soon as stackexchange lets me do it (i.e. in 8 hours)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> \chapter*{Introduction \markboth{INTRODUCTION}{}}

What is the title? The whole argument:

```
Introduction \markboth{INTRODUCTION}{}
```

What happens, if \nameref is used? The whole title including \markboth is called and the execution of `\markboth` changed your header.

Solutions:

- Put `\markboth` *after* `\chapter*`:

  ```
  \chapter*{Introduction}
  \markboth{INTRODUCTION}{}
  ```
- Since version 2009/12/08 v2.34 package `nameref` uses package `gettitlestring`.
  This package knows a title extract method using `expansion` that allows to filter
  stuff out, see package documentation of `gettitlestring`.

  ```
  \GetTitleStringSetup{expand}
  \GetTitleStringDisableCommands{%
    \def\markboth#1#2{\unskip}%
  }
  ```

During title string extraction macro `\markboth` removes its arguments and calls
`unskip` to get rid of the previous space.