# \nameref using 'unexpanded' text?

Tags: macros, hyperref, cross-referencing, counters

Suppose I define a custom command `\exercise` as follows.

```
\newcounter{exercise}
\newcommand\exercise{%
    \refstepcounter{exercise}%
    \section*{Exercise \theexercise}%
}
```

Now, in the following example, I want to use `\nameref` from the `hyperref` package.

```
\exercise\label{ex:first}
foo

\exercise\label{ex:second}
see \nameref{ex:first}

\exercise\label{ex:third}
bar
```

This produces "see Exercise 2" instead of "see Exercise 1". It seems like the 'unexpanded' text is used, expanding into the current counter value. How can I make sure that `\nameref{ex:first}` produces "Exercise 1"?

(Of course, I could just use `Exercise~\ref{ex:first}`, but this is more error-prone. And, in the future, I may want to replace "exercise" by "problem" without having to find and replace all occurences in my document.)

---

Full example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{exercise}
\newcommand\exercise{%
    \refstepcounter{exercise}%
    \section*{Exercise \theexercise}%
}

\begin{document}

\exercise\label{ex:first}
foo

\exercise\label{ex:second}
see \nameref{ex:first}

\exercise\label{ex:third}
bar

\end{document}
```

Comment: As al sys on the site please provide a full but minimal example not sniplets like this. A full but minimal example enables others to copy and test your exact code and not like here we we have to add a lot of code to even test your problem, code that might be different than yours

Comment: @daleif I added a full example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, you need to pass the expansion of `\theexercise`, because `hyperref` doesn't do it to the title.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newcounter{exercise}
\newcommand\exercise{%
  \par % just in case
  \refstepcounter{exercise}%
  \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\section*{\unexpanded{Exercise} \theexercise}%
  }\x
}

\begin{document}

\exercise\label{ex:first}
foo

\exercise\label{ex:second}
see \nameref{ex:first}

\exercise\label{ex:third}
bar

\end{document}
```

This is the (abridged) contents of the `.aux` file:

```
\newlabel{ex:first}{{1}{1}{Exercise 1}{section*.1}{}}
\newlabel{ex:second}{{2}{1}{Exercise 2}{section*.2}{}}
\newlabel{ex:third}{{3}{1}{Exercise 3}{section*.3}{}}
```

It was

```
\newlabel{ex:first}{{1}{1}{Exercise \theexercise }{section*.1}{}}
\newlabel{ex:second}{{2}{1}{Exercise \theexercise }{section*.2}{}}
\newlabel{ex:third}{{3}{1}{Exercise \theexercise }{section*.3}{}}
```

with your code.

**Note.** Why `\unexpanded{Exercise}`? In the particular case it is obviously unnecessary, but it would be for the German “Übung”.

---

You might use `cleveref` instead.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\newcounter{exercise}
\newcommand\exercise{%
  \par % just in case
  \refstepcounter{exercise}%
  \section*{Exercise \theexercise}
}
\crefname{exercise}{Exercise}{Exercises}

\begin{document}

\exercise\label{ex:first}
foo

\exercise\label{ex:second}
see \cref{ex:first}

\exercise\label{ex:third}
bar

\end{document}
```

The output is the same in both cases.

[image]

Can we avoid the `\edef\x{\endgroup` trick? Yes, of course.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{xparse} % not needed for LaTeX 2020-10-01 or later
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\exercise}{}
 {
  \gooz_exercise:ne { \exercisename } { \theexercise }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \gooz_exercise:nn
 {
  \par % just in case
  \refstepcounter{exercise}
  \section*{#1~#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \gooz_exercise:nn { ne }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\exercisename}{Exercise}
\newcounter{exercise}
\crefname{exercise}{\exercisename}{\exercisename s}

\begin{document}

\exercise\label{ex:first}
foo

\exercise\label{ex:second}
see \cref{ex:first} or \nameref{ex:first}

\exercise\label{ex:third}
bar

\end{document}
```

Note that `cleveref` is not necessary, just remove the relevant calls if you prefer `\nameref`.

Comment: if nameref expands or not depends on the option used for gettitlestring. With `\PassOptionsToPackage{expand}{gettitlestring}` the title is expanded (naturally at the costs that fragile stuff can break).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Since what ends up in titles is not known, I'd be wary of using that option.

Comment: imho it is not really problematic: titles have to be more or less expandable anyway for the bookmarks, and you can control the expansion. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66255/2388

Comment: wouldn't it be better to use a numbered section and then just arrange that the heading formatting puts the number last rather than first, rather than using an unnumbered heading and forcing the expansion of the number? (Just leaving it as an exercise for the reader:-)

Comment: @egreg thanks for the comprehensive answer. I had a quick follow-up question: in what case is the `\par` you added necessary?

Comment: @Gooz If you forget a blank line before `\exercise`, the `\refstepcounter` would be executed as part of the preceding paragraph and probably set an improper anchor.